# Why do untracked files get committed?

Tags: git, github, husky

When I type `git status`, I get the output below.

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   services/replication/jobs/go.mod
        new file:   services/replication/jobs/go.sum
        modified:   services/replication/jobs/job.go
Changes not staged for commit:
      ....

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .circleci/pagerduty.sh
        common/nodejs/universal-search/src/utils/aspect_ratio.spec.ts
        common/nodejs/universal-search/src/utils/aspect_ratio.ts
        common/nodejs/universal-search/src/utils/index.ts
        infra/universal_search_apple/pulumi/resources/route53/
```

Then I make a commit with `git commit -m 'Test commit.'`, Somehow, the untracked files show up in the commit.

```
husky > pre-commit (node v14.5.0)
  Finding changed files since git revision b495d278.
  Found 0 changed files.
✅  Everything is awesome!
No staged files match any of provided globs.
[gps-289 b613c603] Test commit.
 15 files changed, 248 insertions(+), 454 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 common/nodejs/universal-search/src/utils/aspect_ratio.spec.ts
 create mode 100644 common/nodejs/universal-search/src/utils/aspect_ratio.ts
 create mode 100644 common/nodejs/universal-search/src/utils/index.ts
 delete mode 100644 external/ambient.d.ts
 delete mode 100644 infra/metadata/Pulumi.dev.yaml
 delete mode 100644 infra/metadata/Pulumi.prod.yaml
...
```

Why do the untracked files show up in the commit even though there were only 3 files under `Changes to be committed?`

Comment: You’re comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: First you talk to git, then you talk to husky. You are talking to two different people about two different things. The way to find out what files are "in the commit" you made with git is to ask _git_.

Answer (score 1):

Untracked files do not get commited. In your case husky staged the untracked files in some of the pre-commit hooks he ran, so at the time of commit those files were not untracked.